# Why does running my globally npm linked package simply open the bin file?

Tags: node.js, npm

If I'm developing the npm package `foo` and I want it to be globally installed as a command-line application, I can do this simply by adding to my package.json:

```
"bin": {
    "foo": "./bin/foo.js"
}
```

Somebody who installs my package globally via npm will have the appropriate batch file and shell script added to their global npm prefix directory. However, suppose I want to be able to launch my package from the shell (or, in the case of Windows, the command prompt). I could do this by creating a batch file/shell script somewhere in one of my PATH directories that simply directly runs my package e.g. `@node C:\my\package\directory\bin\foo %*`.

This is a fairly simple and obvious solution, but I felt that `npm link` was better suited, as it feels less hacky and is theoretically designed to do this exact thing. I run `npm link` in my package directory, then test it by running `foo` from the command line. Rather than executing my script, though, `foo.js` is actually opened in my default editor. Investigating in the prefix directory, it turns out that the `foo.cmd` file (the contents of the `foo` shell script are similar) that npm created contains this:

```
"%~dp0\node_modules\foo\bin\foo.js"   %*
```

Compare with the batch file created by `npm install -g`:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" %*
)
```

Why does `npm link` produce script files that launch a package's bin file instead of launching node with the bin file as an argument? How can I fix this behavior?

Answer (score 18):

The solution is to add `#!/usr/bin/env node` at the beginning of your `bin` script. I have no idea why though. I found out by comparing my script to others that worked.

Comment: It's an instruction to run in a Node environment, which is typically what you want. Otherwise it operates in your normal OS environment, so it's basically acts as if you had double-clicked on the .js file, which would typically open it in an editor (but depends on your OS settings).

Comment: An instruction for what? What software is evaluating this instruction?

Answer (score 0):

What version of `npm` are you running?  Latest is 2.6.0 ;there have been a lot of improvements to npm -- especially around conflicts and race conditions during install -- recently. Can you try updating your npm installation?

To update npm on Windows, follow the instructions here: https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting#upgrading-on-windows

Comment: According to `npm --version`, I'm running 2.6.1. I have no idea how this is possible, given that the package [states rather clearly](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm) that the latest is 2.6.0.

Comment: It looks like you managed to  install `npm@next` which is the pre-release version of `npm`.

The `.cmd` files that `npm` creates are created by the `cmd-shim` package.  If you want to see how that works, you can take a look at https://github.com/ForbesLindesay/cmd-shim

It sounds like you have a feature request for either the `npm` or `cmd-shim` project; I don't believe it's currently possible to make `npm` do what you want here.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I remember installing `npm@next` to solve a different problem I was having, so I believe you're right about that.